# How can I set filter for DateSent to getMessages in Java using Twilio REST API

Tags: java, rest, sms, twilio, message

I am trying to retrieve my SMS log using the REST api but I can't figure out how to filter DateSent to be >= or <= than given date.

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 
Map<String, String> filters = new HashMap<String, String>();
filters.put("DateSent", "2014-04-27");
filters.put("To", "+XXXXXXXXX");    
MessageList messages = client.getAccount().getMessages(filters);
```

According to documentation here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters you are allowed to send >= or <=, but can't figure out where to put the inequality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That Twilio documentation certainly is incomplete and confusing.

Try this: `filters.put("DateSent>", "2014-04-27");`

You can even pass two parameters to retrieve messages between dates:

```
filters.put("DateSent>", "2014-04-20");
filters.put("DateSent<", "2014-04-27");
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. One issue I was having was not getting any Message logs when I removed the Request URL from my number. That was driving me crazy!... Anyways for now this works since I have resorted to poll Messages to see If I get what I want. I know all about the Server Request URL but I used this on a headless client with no capability to be reached outside the network.

Comment: I'm glad that it's working for you now. Please be so kind as to accept this answer as correct. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Is it true the DateSent> includes the value when the DateSend< excludes? Though I've been testing it with times up minutes (NodeJS Twilio SDK formats time for these parameters for me)